# Excel - if, then, find

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm running Excel on Microsoft Office 365. I'm looking to do something rather complicated, I apologize in advanced if this is confusing. Is it possible to incorporate the following steps into an Excel formula?

- [`=SUM(C4:C20)`, which is x]
- [then find value=`Meat` in `E4:E20`]
- [if value=`Meat` is found in `E4:E20`, then read cell 2 spaces to the left (do this for `E4:E20`)]
- [then add all cell 2 spaces to the left =y]
- [then find what percentage y is of x]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What? Would you please elaborate on what you need and break up the question so it's clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `SUMIF` function to get what you want.

I've assumed that your setup for the is something like the following. You've summed up the values in column C, and you want to sum up the values in that same column which are on the  rows which have the word "Meat" in column E. Then you want to divide that second sum by the first sum to obtain a percentage.

SUMIF takes up to three arguments:

1. A range of values, some of which meet a specified criterion
2. The criterion
3. Optionally, the range to be summed if it is different from the first range.

So in this case, the formula will be:

```
=SUMIF(E4:E20,"MEAT",C4:C20)
```

In the screenshot, the total in cell C21 for the range C4:C20 is 153; the SUMIF E21 cell produces a sum of 40 for the four rows that have the word "MEAT" in them; dividing 40 by 153 gives a percentage of 26.1.

[image]

Comment: This is what I understood, too. If he wants the calculation in one cell, he can just use `=SUMIF(E4:E20,"Meat",C4:C20)/SUM(C4:C20)`.